# Is it okay to have this kind of relationship in an ERD?

Tags: database-design

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tKy4.jpg

The Staff connects to the manager and branch

the branch connects to staff and manager.

Note that one branch can only contain one manager.

Questions:

1. If it is wrong, how can I design it?
2. Is it okay if I add two relationships between the tables?
3. Is it possible just to add an attribute such as isManager().

Answer (score 0):

> If it is wrong, how can I design it?

> Is it okay if I add two relationships between the tables?

If a Manager can manage a Branch they're not a Staff of, then it seems fine as-is. Otherwise, Manager.branchNo should be removed since it duplicates what's in the Staff table.

> Is it possible just to add an attribute such as isManager

Yes. This is the simplest in structure. If there's additional information associated with manager, a separate Manager table would prevent cluttering non-manager entries in Staff with null manager data. Otherwise, `SELECT 1 FROM Manager WHERE staffNo = x` checks if Manager.